# Study the convergence of the series

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I need to study the convergence of the following series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot\cdots\cdot(2n+1)}{1\cdot4\cdot7\cdot\cdots\cdot(3n+1)}x^n)^2$$ I tried to expand that term and reduce some terms but didn't succeed, I also tried to apply the ratio test but still nothing. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I do get something from the ratio test, and it works. Can you show your work of the ratio test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ratio test gives you
$${\left(\frac{1 \cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot ...\cdot (2n+1)\cdot (2n+3)}{1\cdot 4\cdot 7\cdot ...\cdot (3n+1)\cdot (3n+4)}x^{n+1}\right)^2\over \left(\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot ...\cdot (2n+1)}{1\cdot 4\cdot 7\cdot ...\cdot (3n+1)}x^n\right)^2}=\frac{(2n+3)^2}{(3n+4)^2} x^2$$
and here you need to take the limit of the ratio. Note that the final result also depends on the value of $x$.

Comment: Clean and simple. I factored out the terms wrong so that's why I couldn't solve it. Thank you!

Comment: Nice one (+1)...

Answer (score 1):

The ratio test helps. Note that $${\left(\frac{1*3*5*...*(2n+3)}{1*4*7*...*(3n+4)}x^{n+1}\right)^2\over \left(\frac{1*3*5*...*(2n+1)}{1*4*7*...*(3n+1)}x^n\right)^2}=\left[{2n+3\over 3n+4}\right]^2 x^2$$and the limit goes to $0$ for $x\in \left(-{3\over 2},{3\over 2}\right)$, therefore the series is convergent over $\left(-{3\over 2},{3\over 2}\right)$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $$\frac{(2n+3)^2}{(3n+4)^2} x^2$$ ?

Comment: What happens when you plug in $n+1$ in $a_n$ to obtain $a_{n+1}$ and then calculate $a_{n+1}\over a_n$?

Comment: I agree with @UnbelieveTable note that it's not $(2n+3)!$ it's $(2n+3)!!$ so $(2n+2)$ is not within either term.

Comment: Sorry for that. I fixed it...